# How to draw(edit) an ascii git tree

Tags: git, text, ascii-art

How the git tree shown in the git documentation like the one below

```
       G   H   I   J
        \ /     \ /
         D   E   F
          \  |  / \
           \ | /   |
            \|/    |
             B     C
              \   /
               \ /
                A
```

is drawn(edited). Is there a specific tool to do it. I have looked at the http://www.asciiflow.com/ which is not very helpful for this purpose.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have natively a way to reproduced that *exact* type of schema, but a git log that this one is a good start:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches --all
```

Answer (score 5):

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit
```

is fine